# Performance improvement with mongo data pagination

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, spring-data-mongodb

I have developed an application using Spring 4, MongoDB, Spring data. In this application I have a mongo collection called Claim. In mongodb We have 400k claim collection.

In the front end I will show this claims as using server side pagination(100 per page). Claim Document looks like following,

```
@Document(Collection = "claims")
public class Claim implements Serializable{
@Id private String id;
@Indexed private int licenseKey;
private int claimNumber;
private int chartNumber;
private String profile;
private String status;


....

private LocalDate doe;
private LocalDate dos;
```

}

Claim document has 53 properties. We are using 20 fields as for ordering. Ex-: doe, dos, claimNumber, etc.

My Question is when we order through this huge collection it will take considerable time. I wanna performance vice improvement. We use restfull calls for get data to the front-end and front-end displays it with lightning speed.

Only delay I have in pagination and ascending and descending ordering with back end calls. How do I improve my performance.